# How can I get PhpStorm to stop on breakpoints in `vendor` folders?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I have PhpStorm and XDebug set up and working fine in my own project code.

However when I need to debug something within the `vendor` folder, PhpStorm does not stop at the breakpoint.

How do I set this up?

Comment: what versions are you running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the issue - PhpStorm had auto mapped the `public` directory of my project, but needed to be told where to find the root
[image: server settings]